# Updating res.locals after each var change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to build my own flash messages, but in a way easier way. It looks like this:

```js
var errCode = 0;

router.use(function(req, res, next)
{
    res.locals.errCode = errCode;
    next();
});

router.post('/login', middleware.access, function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return next(err); errCode = 1;}
      if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); errCode = 2;}
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); errCode = 1;}
        return res.redirect('/regiune/' + req.body.regiune);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

and in the EJS

```html
<% if(errCode === 1){ %>
        <span class="login-error">err1</span><br/>
        <% } %>
        <% if(errCode === 2){ %>
            <span class="login-error">err2</span><br/>
        <% } %>
        <% if(errCode === 3){ %>
            <span class="login-error">err3</span><br/>
        <% } %>
```

The problem with my idea is that errCode gets passed with the value 0 because that's the value it had in the first place. Is there any way to make res.locals.errCode update whenever errCode gets changed?

Comment: Using a global variable to pass data between routes/middlewares is a really bad idea, because you always have to assume that there might be two requests hitting your server at the same time, and then the `errorCode` will be overwritten by one request, before it can be used by the other request for rendering. You have to store the request/response/task dependent variables with the corresponding object.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. How can I easily implement flash messages then?

Comment: You need to use session handling, pass the message as url parameter with the redirect, or do no redirect at all, but render the page for the `post` with the given error message. Flash messages aren't an easy task at all if you want to deal with all edge cases.

Comment: I don't want to redirect. Check my example of what I tried to do. Can you please help me do it? I have no idea how and I think I will need this skill.

Comment: I looked at your code and I mentioned three different ways to solve it. Besides that your code is not clear and does not make to much sense. Anyhow if you want to use the `errCode` without any redirect, then why don't you write `res.locals.errCode=1;` instead of `errCode = 1;`? Using the `res` object is how you pass data between different middlewares for the same request.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I change that and still use that router.use I get this: "ReferenceError: errCode is not defined". If I delete router.use and I just use res.locals.errCode = 1, I will get this error from ejs: "errCode is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a global variable to pass data between routes/middlewares is a really bad idea, because you always have to assume that there might be two requests hitting your server at the same time, and then the `errorCode` will be overwritten by one request, before it can be used by the other request for rendering. You have to store the request/response/task dependent variables with the corresponding object.

And you never set `errorCode` to something differenten then `0`. Because you always have a return statement before it e.g.:

```
return next(err); // the function is exit here before the next statement is executed
errCode = 1; // is never executed because this is unreachable code
```

The middlewares are executed in the order they are attached, so if you write:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
})

router.post('/login', middleware.access, function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
})
```

Then the code of the use is executed before the on of the post, so even if the `errCode` would have ben set then the `res.locals.errCode = errCode` would be execute before the `errCode` was set so it would get the previous value of `errCode`.

So you code has to look like this:

```
router.post('/login', middleware.access, function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.locals.errCode = 1;
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      res.locals.errCode = 2;
      // THIS WON'T WORK: because the `res.locals.errCode` will not 
      // survive the redirect you need to use sessions here or pass the 
      // error with the redirect
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.locals.errCode = 1;
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.redirect('/regiune/' + req.body.regiune);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: If I don't use router.use() so I can define errCode I get this from my ejs: Cannot read property 'errCode' of undefined.

Comment: @AndreiDaniel that your ejs setup is not able to read the values that are stored in `locals` is a completely different topic then your question. It is only possible to tell you what  the problem is if you show how you setup and use the ejs renderer.